# UDF with passed multi-area-range as parameter breaks on deletion of another Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

consider a UDF like this (abbreviated):

```
Public Function ffifneps(wo As Range, pre As Variant, suf As Variant) As String
Dim z As Range, e As String
...
For Each z In wo
    If CStr(z.Value) <> "" Then
        If (Len(e) > 0) Then e = e & ", "
        e = e & maske & z.Value & maske
    End If
Next z
...
```

Using this UDF from Sheet1, with *wo* being a multi-area-range on Sheet1 like e.g.

```
=ffifneps((B37:B38;B137:B138);C37:C38;". ")
```

the UDF gets recalculated on the insertion or deletion of another worksheet and then applies the relative range to the worksheet then visible, yielding unexpected results.

If I pass a single-area-range like

```
=ffifneps(B37:B38;C37:C38;". ")
```

everything is fine.

The same happens, BTW, if looking at the Areas, like e.g.

```
...
For Each z In pre.Areas
    e = e & "'" & z.Parent.Name & "'!" & z.Address
    i = i + 1
    If (pre.Areas.Count > 1) And (i < pre.Areas.Count) Then e = e & ", "
Next z
...
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:** For the time being, I patched it up like this:

```
...
If (TypeName(Application.Caller) = "Range") Then
    If (wo.Areas.Count > 1) Then Set wo = Application.Caller.Parent.Range(wo.Address)
    If (TypeName(pre) = "Range") Then If (pre.Areas.Count > 1) Then Set pre = Application.Caller.Parent.Range(pre.Address)
    If (TypeName(suf) = "Range") Then If (suf.Areas.Count > 1) Then Set suf = Application.Caller.Parent.Range(pre.Address)
End If
```

Ugly, I know, and the UDF thus cannot be used any more with real cross-worksheet-ranges, if they are multi-area.
But I keep wondering?
    ...

Comment: Use two nested loops: first loops through Areas and the inner loop through each Area's Cells.

Comment: Won't change anything. Put `Public Function testmr(arng As Range, brng As Range) As String : 
    Dim aa As Range, c As Range  :
    For Each aa In arng.Areas  :
        For Each c In aa.Cells  :
            Debug.Print c.Address(external:=True)  :
        Next c  :
    Next aa  :
End Function`
in a new book, enter the formula in Sheet1 with a multi-area-reference, switch to Sheet3 and delete Sheet 4. The output will reference Sheet3, not Sheet1 at least in Excel 2003

Comment: I don't see that behavior (XP, XL2007). Output always references sheet1.  Also, there's no recalculation on worksheet insertion, only on deletion.